# Laravel convert resultset to array

Tags: php, arrays, laravel-5.4

Database table `SITE` has many columns. One of them is `site_id`. I need all the `site_id`s as an array since it has to be fed to a method which accepts only a string array.

What I tried so far is:

```
$sites = DB::select('select site_id from site_tab');
$sites_arr = $sites->toArray();
```

But this doesn't produce the result I want. I need `$sites_arr` to be like `['A','B','C',...]`

Please suggest a way to get this done. A solution based on Eloquent is also OK for me.

Thanks

Comment: try this  `DB::table('site_tab')->pluck('site_id')->toArray();`

Comment: This solution works. How can I make this the Solution? You have put it as a comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
DB::table('site_tab')->pluck('site_id')->toArray();
```

reference [pluck](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/queries#retrieving-results)

referen [toArray](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/collections#method-toarray)

Answer (score 0):

If you open a [manual](https://laravel.com/docs/master/database#running-queries), you will see that

> The `select` method will always return an `array` of results

So, there's no need to use `->toArray()`, as result is **already** an array.

To get values as array of names you can do:

```
$site_ids = DB::table('site_tab')->pluck('site_id');
```

Using `->toArray()` here is optional, as you can iterate over `$site_ids` (which is a `Collection`) with a `foreach` too.

Comment: But the manual says "Each result within the array will be a PHP  `StdClass` object". I want each result to be `string`. Not type of `StdClass`.

Comment: That's why you need to iterate over result and extract your values. `toArray` does not do it.